# Static IP settings not taking effect for hostonly network

Tags: networking, vmware

I have a virtual machine with 3 NIC's.

2 are connected to a host only network. 
1 is connected to the internet

I statically assigned an IP address to one of the hostonly networks. When I run `ip addr` the new network configuration does not show up.

Here is the static configuration for ens192.

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
DEFROUTE=yes
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=ens192
UUID=db6fbd50-961f-4c6f-9078-8aa82a0e8640
DEVICE=ens192
ONBOOT=YES
IP_ADDRESS=10.2.10.5
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
```

Below is the output of ip addr

```
3: ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:f2:e1:df brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fef2:e1df/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: ens224: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
```

Please let me know if you have any questions and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried restarting your network service? You won't have any changes take effect unless you 1. Reboot or 2. Stop & start or restart your network service.

- Centos 6.5 Ex: > `$ service network restart`
- Centos 7 Ex: > `$ systemctl restart network`
- Ubuntu/Debian Ex: > `$ service networking restart`

Comment: I have done both. No change.

Comment: You don't have your gateway in your configuration, also is this your eth0 file under /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts ?

Comment: The network does not require a default gateway. From openstack, "

Its just internal traffic.
Instance tunnels on 10.0.1.0/24 without a gateway

[Note] Note
This network does not require a gateway because communication only occurs among network and compute nodes in your OpenStack environment." I have edited the file above.

Comment: Ah ok so its local. Hmmm, At this point it doesnt seems like there should be any errors.  Could you try stripping this file to its bare minimum.  The ipaddress,  network,  device name, bootproto,  and onboot. Just to see if we can get some traffic on it.

Comment: Something like this. ipaddress,  network,  device=ens192, bootproto=none, userctl=no and onboot=yes